# Como eu posso fazer uma verificação com `if` se a palavra digitada é igual a alguma palavra de uma lista de strings em C?

Tags: c

exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

char input[20];
char* strings[] = {"maça","banana"};

printf("tente acertar uma das minhas frutas favoritas:\n");
scanf("%s", input);

if(input == strings[]){
     printf("parabens! você acertou %s é uma das minhas frutas favoritas!", input);
}else{
printf("você errou!");
     }
}
```

Comment: Procure pela função `strcmp`

Comment: Imagino que deva fazer um loop para comparar a entrada com as opções, ou até um `switch`... Coloca mais informações na sua questão, o que sua função está retornando...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sugiro definir um tamanho para seu `char * strings[]` e utilizar `strcmp` para comparar strings ao invés de `==`. Veja o exemplo a baixo, além de comparar utilizando `strcmp` tem um loop `for` para percorrer o array e uma flag para auxiliar se foi encontrado ou não.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TAMANHO 10

int main(){
    
    int acertou = 0;
    char input[20];
    char* strings[TAMANHO] = {"maça","banana"};
    
    printf("tente acertar uma das minhas frutas favoritas:\n");
    scanf("%s", input);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < TAMANHO; i++) {
        if(strcmp(input, strings[i]) == 0) {
            printf("parabens! você acertou %s é uma das minhas frutas favoritas!\n", strings[i]);
            acertou = 1;
            break;
        } 
    }
    if (acertou == 0) {
       printf("você errou!\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```